# How to include another macro in a macro?

Tags: ios, swift, macros

I tried to write a simple macro, but the error "Expected macro expansion to produce an expression" occurred when calling.

Macro implementation

```
public struct Log14: ExpressionMacro {
    public static func expansion(
        of node: some FreestandingMacroExpansionSyntax,
        in context: some MacroExpansionContext
    ) -> ExprSyntax {
        return
"""
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    os_log(.debug, "\\(0)")
}
"""
    }
}
```

Comment: If macro does not work inside macro , put the macro in another method that you call in your macro.

Comment: I'm just lazy. I don't want to write a lot of `if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { ... }` outside. HAHAHA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#available` is not a macro. It *looks like* a macro because it also starts with `#`, but it's just a special syntax to specify availability. It doesn't expand to anything - the compiler is hard coded to treat these specially.

The problem is not about putting macros in macros. Putting another macro inside a macro's expansion would work the way you expect.

The problem here is that

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    os_log(.debug, "\(0)")
}
```

is not an expression. Your `ExpressionMacro` is supposed to expand to an expression. The `if` here is a *statement*.

Freestanding macros right now cannot generate *statements*. One way to work around this right now is to generate a *closure expression* that gets immediately called. That is, return this as the expansion:

```
"""
{
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        os_log(.debug, "\\(0)")
    }
}()
"""
```

This doesn't work with any kind of statement, namely statements that is sensitive to scope, like `return`, `defer`, `break` etc. But for an if statement, this work around works.

Comment: It took me a long time to figure out that `Freestanding macros right now cannot generate statements.`. I found it particularly difficult because the freestanding declaration macro I was trying to use to generate statements  seemed to work in unit tests, but caused the compiler to crash in actual code usage. What finally led me down the right path, to use a freestanding expression macro (with the pattern you use above of generating a closure expression) was the debug diagnostics in the unit tests when I ran them. Which were something like ` error: unexpected code before declaration`.